# tsc ignoring .yaml file even though it's set to include in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

When I run `$ tsc` at the root directory, it completely ignores my `src/schemas/verification-openapi.yaml` file and doesn't make it to the `dist/` folder. However, I have `"src/**/*.yaml"` inside the `"includes"` section.

`app/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.yaml",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

`app/src` folder:

[image]

`app/dist/src` folder:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may need to make a packaging script to execute copy files after build